# plot 2D intensity figure in 3D coordinate system

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D intensity plot, as in this example:

```
[xx yy] = meshgrid(0:0.1:1, 0:0.1:1);

figure(1)
imagesc(sin(xx)) %(x,y)-plot at z=0
```

Now, as I have noted in the comment, this plot is in the `xy`-plane and I have taken `z=0`. I'd like to plot this in a 3D coordinate system as a function of `x` and `y`, but taking `z=0`. I tried with `plot3` in this way, `plot3(xx,yy,cos(yy))`, but that only plots lines and gives them a curvature which I am not interested in. I'd like only a plane at `z=0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `surf` to accomplish this. We use the `xx` and `yy` meshgrid outputs as the `x` and `y` positisions, a matrix of `zeros` as the `z` value and `sin(xx)` as the color. We also remove the edges by setting the `EdgeColor` to `none`.

```
surf(xx, yy, zeros(size(xx)), sin(xx), 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is nice